# Fill drop down of GitHub workflow dynamically (with list of branches)

Tags: github, github-actions

in case I create a workflow in GitHub Actions, that has to be triggered manually, the following dialog will appear:

[image]

I would like to add a second drop down menu containing a list of all branches of the current repository (or even of another repository if possible). I guess this must be possible because this is also the content of the drop down added by GitHub.

I found a way to add a drop down:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      service:
        type: choice
        description: branch to build from
        options:
          - development
          - main
          - test
          - ...
```

But I did not found a possibility to fill this list dynamically. (e.g. adding the result of `git branch -r`)

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: I don't think there's any way for your own inputs to have a dynamic list of choices. Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70350569/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe: This is not good news :( Thanks for taking the time to reply.